# querying LDAP - get account status (like disabled , active, etc.)

Tags: windows, ldap

I am querying a LDAP and setting variables for mail and displayName. I also need to get account is disable or active. Which property should I need to pull for this?

Comment: That depends on the specific LDAP product.  In some cases it may also depend on how the system administrator chose to configure it.

Comment: Harry is bang on; it depends what you are using.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If using Active Directory the attribute you are interested in is `userAccountControl` which is a bit mask.  Here are the possible values... http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305144/

There is no standard attribute though and it will vary by product and sometimes applications that use the directory server as a repository.

Comment: hmmm... shoudl be `512` for enabled accounts and `514` for disabled accounts (i.e. the NORMAL_ACCOUNT and ACCOUNTDISABLE bits are both set)

Comment: Dave you are correct. 514 for disabled and 512 for enabled accounts. (&(objectClass=user)(samaccountname=userAccount)) and using UserAccountControl

Answer (score 0):

We have auto unlock after 5min via GPO enabled on our network. With this setting, the `userAccountControl` field remains unchanged until the user logs in. So we have currently no way to find out if a user is still logged or not by querying LDAP.